Managing Complex Data with SharedPreferences in School ERP Apps
I'm currently working on three ERP apps for schools in a small IT company. Each app implements multiple login functionality using SharedPreferences to store user data. However, the data is quite complex, including student details, school details, and app configurations.
It is very hard for me to maintain the codebase. Sometimes the app crashes when I logged in mutliple student. I am concerned about the performance of these apps. It crashes a lot.
How should I refactor the code? I am not expert in android development as It is my first job. So do you have any advice or best practices on managing such complex data would be greatly appreciated!

SharedPreferences are good for app configurations but for complex data like student details, school details, etc. you should consider using some database like SQLite using Room.

Thank you for response. I will start refactoring the code.

sure, let me know if you have any difficulty in doing the same

I am bit stuck like how would I implement mutliple logins. I mean I can store details but for mutli-logins I am blank.

Store the user credentials after encrypting them, decrypt and use the credentials of the selected user.
